# SockJS multiplexing example 404 index.html not found

Tags: node.js, sockjs

Looking at [SockJS multiplex example](https://github.com/sockjs/websocket-multiplex/tree/master/examples/sockjs)

I got the server running.  When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:9999/multiplex`  I see a welcome message "`Welcome to SockJS!`"

When I try to browser to index.hmtl  `http://127.0.0.1:9999/index.html` I get 404 message "`Cannot GET /index.html`"

The '`index.html`' is in the same directory as the `server.js` is running. Why can't the server find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed express 3.1.1 and made some [code updates to server.js](https://gist.github.com/dev-e-loper/5332522).  Now when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:9999/` it serves me index.html as specified in server:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Not sure why but `http://127.0.0.1:9999/index.html` still doesn't give me the file.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check if you're using good express version. Express 3 changed API's and code may require some tweaking. See sockjs-node/examples for examples.

Comment: ran `npm list` my express version is 2.5.8 as specified in the package.json file. I upgraded to express 3.1.1, made code changes and still experiencing same behavior. Here is the code for my server - https://gist.github.com/dev-e-loper/5332522